No sound on ubuntu 24 "Dummy output"
I installed ubuntu 24 on my system (not upgrade), and i have "Dummy output" in the sound system. No sound at all.
when i type lspci-v i get:
Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 200 Series PCH HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 145, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at f7240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at f7220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_avs

Running hdajackretask i get the message "no codecs found sorry"
I tried a lot of things i found online, no sucess..;
Thanks

Thanks kanehekili for your reply !

I guess I'll have to install an older driver. any idea how to proceed ? https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-a2f0-1458-a182    is where i have to download it ?  Thanks a lot

This looks like a failure of your Audio drivers. A short check (search for "Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio") will lead you to this site.
It states that it should work with Ubuntu until 23.04 but failed with Debian 11 (on which Ubuntu is based). Try to probe for a driver as described there.
Since your subsystem is Gigabyte and not MSI your miles may vary. This ArchLinux Thread displays some intricate information about the system - you could compare your internal info with that.
Last not least you could switch to pipewire (if not already installed) as described in my answer
